# Use aggregation in mongodb to perform update after query matches

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a mongodb query where i am using aggregates, my query is given below

```
couponmodel.aggregate(
    { $match : { 'brand_id': { $in: brand_ids } } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, arr_size: { $size: "$coupon_codes" }, curr_ctr:1 } },
    function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {

        } else {
            if (docs.length > 0) {
                console.log('docs: ', docs);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Now the problem i am facing is after match query i want to delete(pull) this brand_id from my brand_ids which is an array, because i want to use match query for remaining brand_ids

Can anyone please tell me how can do this.

thank you.

**UPDATE- As i think i have not clearly mentioned what i am trying to do consider below case**

Suppose my brand_ids array contains these strings

```
brand_ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"]
```

and my database have below documents

```
{
   "brand_id": "id1",
   "name": "Levis",
   "loc": "india"
},
{
   "brand_id": "id1",
   "name": "Levis"
   "loc": "america"
},
{
   "brand_id": "id2",
   "name": "Lee"
   "loc": "india"
},
{
   "brand_id": "id2",
   "name": "Lee"
   "loc": "america"
}
```

Desired JSON output

```
   {
       "name": "Levis"
    },
    {
       "name": "Lee"
    }
```

Now for above query i want to get results with only one "Levis" and one "Lee", but as they appear twice in the document they will be returned twice that's why when first "Levis" appears i want to remove it from brand_ids such that next "Levis" will not get returned and same is the case for "Lee". Also i am doing this to reduce query time so don't give me answer like group query with brand names and all.

Hope my question is clear now.

**UPDATE- As everone is telling me to use group now let me tell you why i think it will increase time taken by query.**

For above example suppose i have 25000 documents with "name" as "Levis" and 25000 of documents where "name" is "Lee", now if i will use group then all of 50000 documents will be queried and grouped by "name".

But according to the solution i want, when first document with "Levis" and "Lee" gets found then i will don't have to look for remaining thousands of the  documents.

Hope you get it, **Actually my question is how to use findOne on every element of my array and when i get any element then don't look for it.**

Comment: You could do a second query/aggregate for $nin: brand_ids ?  I'm not sure on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: i want to remove the brand_id which matches from brand_ids array, actually i want to perform search for every brand_ids but if any brand id found a match then i don't want to search for it again got that ??

Comment: There is no way to do without $group. $match runs a single query and I doubt that a single query has any way to ignore a matching document.

Comment: by using group how can i do that ?? can you please tell me.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the desired JSON output?

Comment: i have edited my question also @chridam please note that i dont want to use group as it will not reduce query time that'w why i want to do something with brand_ids so that when i first found "Levis" then i don't have to look for it again.

Comment: db.collection.findOne({name:"Levis",brand_id:{$in:["id1","id2","id3"]}}) will this solve your problem ? you can search on name and do a lookup for id in the id's array as soon as there is first hit mongo wont query further.

Answer (score 2):

Still not 100% sure what you're trying but this will create a result document of length 1, with distinct values for all matches of brand_ids.

Then in the result, it will iterate through all of the brands and remove them from your brand_ids array.

```
couponmodel.aggregate(
    { $match: { "brand_id": { $in: brand_ids } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, brands: { $addToSet: "$brand_id" } } },
    function(err, doc) {
        doc.brands.forEach(function(brand) {
            var idx = array.indexOf(brand);
            if (idx > -1) {
                brand_ids.splice(idx, 1);    
            }
        });
    }
)
```

Comment: Please see i have edited my question hope now you can understand what i am trying to do. Also i dont think your answer will work because i want to remove brand ids when i am querying in mongodb not after i fetch the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
couponmodel.aggregate(
        { "$match" : { 'brand_id': { $in: brand_ids } } },
        { "$group": { _id: name, "name" : {"$first":"$name"}}},
        {"$project" : {name : "$name","_id" : false}},
        function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Razor_pay_webhook Error 2 err: " + err);
                res.json({success : 0, message : "Sorry Please Try Again"});
                return next();
            } else {
                if (docs.length > 0) {
                    console.log('docs: ', docs);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```