# Mongo Db : $lookup (aggregation) / join with two different data types

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use mongo 3.4 $lookup:function

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "inventory",
          localField: "item",
          foreignField: "sku",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])

orders:
{ "_id" : 1, "itemid" : "1234", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 }

invdentory :
{ "_id" : 1, "skuid" : 123, description: "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
```

The problem here is the fields to be joined are of string and integer. How can i make this lookup possible in mongo

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to change the datatype inside the $lookup step of the aggregation pipeline. The topic has already been discussed here:

- [Change type of field inside mongoDB aggregation and does $lookup utilises index on fields or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41042482/4731408)
- [how to convert string to numerical values in an aggregate query in MongoDB.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29487351/4731408)

In both threads the final solution was: *you must previously convert the datatype programmatically*